# Get paragraph after a certain symbol in Python

Tags: python, text, extract, paragraph

I am a python beginner.

I have a large txt file in the following format, made of many one sentence paragraphs:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

****
Sed id placerat magna.

*******
Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique. 

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.
```

I am trying to get output as **only the paragraphs** following **the asterisks paragraph** [ minimum 4 asterisks per **asterisks paragraph** ].

The output I need:

```
Sed id placerat magna.

Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.
```

I was trying something like this, but I have no idea A] how to set the minimum 4 asterisks per **asterisks paragraph** and B] how to set **the paragraph after the asterisks paragraph**.

```
import re

article_content = [open('text.txt').read() ]

after_asterisk_article_paragraph = []
 
string = "****"
after_asterisk_article_paragraph = string[string.find("****")+4:]

print(*after_asterisk_article_paragraph, sep='\n\n')
```

Again, I am just starting Python so please excuse me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might read the whole file and use a pattern to match at least 4 times an asterix, followed by all lines that are not empty or start with 4 times an asterix.

```
^\*{4,}((?:\r?\n(?!\s*$|\*{4}).+)*)
```

- `^\*{4,}` Match 4 or more times `*` from the start of the string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\r?\n` Match a newline
    - `(?!\s*$|\*{4}).+` Match the whole line if it is not empty or starts with 4 times `*` using a negative lookahead `(?!`
  - `)*` Optionally repeat the group
- `)` Close capture group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1z2jyt/1)

For example using re.findall which will return the capture group 1 value:

```
import re
file = open('text.txt', mode='r')
result = [s.strip() for s in re.findall(r'^\*{4,}((?:\r?\n(?!\s*$|\*{4}).+)*)', file.read(), re.MULTILINE)]
print(result)
file.close()
```

Output

```
['Sed id placerat magna.', 'Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.']
```

Comment: Is there a way to get Output such that each sentence is one paragraph? I cannot seem to figure out how to add something like this to the code above: `split_article_content = [] for element in article_content: split_article_content += re.split("(?<=[.!?])\s+", element)`

Comment: That code will split the text after a `.` `!` or `?` and add the items to a list `split_article_content` Is that not what you want?

Comment: Sorry. Rather I need the code to split the `'` as so the output gives one sentence per paragraph.